# How do I correct a mistaken commit in master I did?

Tags: git

I made the following mistake and would like to correct it.

I have a git repo that is cloned of a remote repo.
In it there is the master branch.
I wanted to correct a bug there so I did ***mistakenly***

```
git checkout -m BugCorrection
```

I didn't realize I had misspelled it! so after that I did

```
git add main.py
git commit -m "corrected bug"
```

Then I realized I had commited into the main branch!!

So now I have a main branch that is one commit ahead of the origin/main

After that I did

```
git checkout -b BugCorrection
git push origin BugCorrection
```

to push my changes
but how do I restore main to be the same as origin/main??

Comment: isn't it possible via

git checkout main and then run hard reset 

git reset --hard origin/main

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid it would create another commit but it worked as wished.